# Spring MVC 4 @RequestParam DTO mandatory attributes

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, servlets

I've created a DTO object that contains as many attributes as parameters my @RestController needs to receive. Some of them are mandatory and others are not.

The controller method looks as follows:

```
@RequestMapping(path = "/endpoint_url", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public List<ReturnDTO> endpoint(@RequestParam(required = false) FilterDTO filter) { ... }
```

I want to know if there's any way to make some of the FilterDTO attributes mandatory similarly as it's done with the **@RequestParam(required = true)** annotation.

I've tried the **@NotNull** annotation from *javax.validation.constraints.NotNull* but it doesn't seem to work.

Any ideas are kindly appreciated!

Comment: https://sdqali.in/blog/2015/12/04/validating-requestparams-and-pathvariables-in-spring-mvc/

Comment: Don't use `@RequestParam` use `@ModelAttribute` if you want to bind request attributes to an object. Add `@Valid` and put `@NotNull` or `@NotEmpty` on the fields that are required in the dto.

Comment: This solution worked like a charm! Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

The idea is that you will need to use @Validated or @Valid from org.springframework.validation.annotation with your @RequestBody object
so it will look like this

```
@RequestMapping(path = "/endpoint_url", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public List<ReturnDTO> endpoint(@Validated @RequestParam FilterDTO filter){}
```

then all variables in the FilterDTO are optional unless you add @NotNull annotation to them

so it will be as

```
@NotNull
private String name
```

this mean name cannot be null or exception will be thrown

Comment: A GET Call cannot have @RequestBody.